# getBoundingClientRect is not a function on vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to find the top and bottom edge of a div when i move my cursor over it. The div is generated dynamically. However, it produced error message

> getBoundingClientRect is not a function

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(i, index) in divs" :key="index">
            <div :ref="'ref_' + index" @mouseover="divDragOver($event, index)">
                This is div {{ index }}
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default{
  methods: {
    divDragOver(e, i){
      var divTop = this.$refs["ref_" + i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
      console.log(divTop);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: There's no need for dynamic refs. [Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-sutherland-utz1w?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) an easy way of getting the `top`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `event.target` as another user suggested which is, I think, the cleanest way

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(i, index) in divs" :key="index">
      <div ref="myDiv" @mouseover="divDragOver">This is div {{ index }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return { divs: [1, 2, 3, 4] };
  },
  methods: {
    divDragOver(event) {
      console.log(event.target); // this will be your mouseover div
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

---

For your issue though, based on Vue.js [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html):

> When `ref` is used together with `v-for`, the `ref` you get will be an **array** containing the child components mirroring the data source.

So you don't have to use the index on your `ref` creation, while you will end up with `divs.length` arrays which their first element will be your reference.

If you had to use `refs`:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(i, index) in divs" :key="index">
      <div ref="myDiv" @mouseover="divDragOver($event, index)">This is div {{ index }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return { divs: [1, 2, 3, 4] };
  },
  methods: {
    divDragOver(e, i) {
      console.log(this.$refs.myDiv); // this will be an array with all your refs, use i to access
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

So you were getting an error because your element's `ref` was on `this.$refs["ref_" + i][0]`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="index in divs" :key="index">
      <div :ref="'ref_' + index" @mouseover="divDragOver($event, index)">
        This is div {{ index }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    divs: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  }),
  methods: {
    divDragOver(e, i) {
      let [div] = this.$refs['ref_' + i];
      let top = div.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      console.log(top);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Your code doesn't work, because the `this.refs` return an Array.

Comment: Thanks. You solved my problem. But what on Earth "let [div]" is????

Comment: There are two different things here. First `let` [declares a block-scoped local variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). Second `[div]` is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this problem by accessing the target element in the event:

```js
<script>
export default{
  methods: {
    divDragOver(e){
      var divTop = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      console.log(divTop);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are mistaken, the `$refs` isn't a component. See the documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, just add `$el` like this

```
var divTop = this.$refs["ref_" + i].$el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```